# Does OS X store my complete install history?

Tags: macos, install, logs

I'm running 10.6.8 and wondering where my Mac stores my install history -- I'm thinking everything from Ruby gems to full blown web apps. Does such a general file exist?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what install history?  Is it an application install history or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look in /var/log for `install.log` and `install.log.[something].bz2`.  `install.log` contains the most current logs; the other files are archives of successively older log files, made whenever each one reached a maximum size.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.